# Build file 'C:\deal_diligence\android\build.gradle' line: 11

Tags: flutter, dart, build.gradle

I'm getting a build error in the build.gradle file on line #11.

I have removed the "new" keyword from the file but I still get the error.

Here is my build.gradle file:

```
def localProperties = Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    namespace "com.natekane.deal_diligence"
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.natekane.deal_diligence"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.3.1")
}
```

Here is the full error message from the debug window:

```
Build file 'C:\deal_diligence\android\build.gradle' line: 11

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> Could not find method id() for arguments [com.google.gms.google-services] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

Everything I have found so far says for me to delete the "new" keyword.

I am trying to add Firebase to the app so maybe I messed up the other build.gradle file too?

What else can I do?
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not find method id() for arguments \[com.google.gms.google-services\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73859059/could-not-find-method-id-for-arguments-com-google-gms-google-services)

Comment: Thanks but I have already gone through that post and made any adjustments to my code based on the answers there and it didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error already stated that error at 'Build file 'C:\deal_diligence\android\build.gradle' line: 11"

Which means in android/build.gradle file, but you sharing us the app/build.gradle file.

Try check the android/build.gradle file and add below line inside the dependencies {...} if not you haven't :

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my mistake of looking at the wrong file. Here is the dependencies from the correct file:  dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        id("com.google.gms.google-services") version "4.3.15" apply false
    }    Should I have classpath instead of id?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help. I was able to get past this error by making the change to my android/build.gradle file and I needed to add the "new" key word to line 1 in my app/build.gradle file.